# Swift 4 Firebase Realtime Database nested dictionary

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

ZERO experience, so bear with me...

Im trying to retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime Database and im using this code..

```
  func fetchData(){
    refHandle = ref?.child("caddata").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let values = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable: Any] {

            for value in values.values {
                print (value)
```

"values" shows the following:

```
▿ 1 element
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
▿ key : AnyHashable("parsedContent")
  - value : "parsedContent"
▿ value : 1 element
  ▿ 0 : 7 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : location
      - value : 1234 ANY ADDRESS ST ANYTOWN
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - key : agencyId
      - value : 3-08
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - key : alarmLevel
      - value : 0
    ▿ 3 : 2 elements
      - key : agencyEventSubtypeCode
      - value : 59-C-3O
    ▿ 4 : 2 elements
      - key : originatingAction
      - value : CadEventNew
    ▿ 5 : 2 elements
      - key : agencyEventId
      - value : CC17187712
    ▿ 6 : 2 elements
      - key : dateTime
      - value : 2017-12-22T22:37:27Z
```

Which I believe you'd refer to as a nested dictionary.  "value" prints:

```
▿ 1 element
  ▿ 0 : 7 elements
▿ 0 : 2 elements
  - key : location
  - value : 1234 ANY ADDRESS ST ANYTOWN
▿ 1 : 2 elements
  - key : agencyId
  - value : 3-08
▿ 2 : 2 elements
  - key : alarmLevel
  - value : 0
▿ 3 : 2 elements
  - key : agencyEventSubtypeCode
  - value : 59-C-3O
▿ 4 : 2 elements
  - key : originatingAction
  - value : CadEventNew
▿ 5 : 2 elements
  - key : agencyEventId
  - value : CC17187712
▿ 6 : 2 elements
  - key : dateTime
  - value : 2017-12-22T22:37:27Z
```

I have no idea how to get into the next level or levels to retrieve the value for each key shown.  The end goal is to show some or all of the data in a tableview.  Like I said, I have no experience.  Any help (in the simplest terms) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your value is another dictionary. So

```
if let dict = value as Dictionary {
    for key in dict.allKeys {
        print("the value for key \(key) is:")
        print(dict[key])
    }
}
```